# Find specific text between words using Regex

Tags: javascript, java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regular-language

I'm trying to replace some string but I have the condition which is that this string must be inside a "tag". 
How could I do this using regex?

For example:

```
Text multiline, bla bla bla **FOO** text text text 
*START_TAG* text text  text text **FOO** a lot of texts
**FOO**  more text
*END_TAG*
```

I would like to replace *FOO* text which is between **START_TAG** and **END_TAG**

I tried doing something like this:

```
(?<=word1)(.*?)(?=word2)
```

or

```
(?<=word1)FOO(?=word2)
```

But in the first case I get everything inside the tag and in the second nothing is found.

I searched a lot but people use to search for a string inside parentheses or all text between word, etc.

I'm using Java for doing this, but could also be in javascript.

Comment: So, you are working in Java, right? Please be specific when it comes to tagging.

Comment: Sorry. Just added.

Comment: The solutions can be identical, but for Java, there is a one regex solution. Do you want to replace *all* occurrences of `FOO` between those words?

Comment: Yes... exactly.

Comment: Because I have a string read from a file and I must keep it unchanged, except for this word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you may use a one-regex solution like

```
String result = s.replaceAll("((?:\\G(?!\\A)|START_TAG)(?:(?!START_TAG|FOO).)*?)FOO(?=.*END_TAG)", "$1<REPLACED>");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MNwzOt/2).

**Details**

- `((?:\\G(?!\\A)|START_TAG)(?:(?!START_TAG|FOO).)*?)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:\\G(?!\\A)|START_TAG)` - the end of the previous match or `START_TAG`
  - `(?:(?!START_TAG|FOO).)*?)` - any char, 0+ repetitions, as few as possible, that does not start a `START_TAG` and `FOO` char sequences
- `FOO` - a `FOO` to match and replace
- `(?=.*END_TAG)` - a positive lookahead to check there is `END_TAG` to the right of the current location.

In JS, a two step replacement seems to be best:

```js
var rx = /START_TAG[\s\S]*?END_TAG/g;
var str = "Text multiline, bla bla bla **FOO** text text text *START_TAG* text text text text **FOO** a lot of texts\n**FOO**  more text\n*END_TAG*";
var result = str.replace(rx, function ($0) {return $0.replace(/FOO/g, "<REPLACED>");} );
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just tested, it's almost there. The only problem is that words like FOOTER, or FOOBAR, would also be changed. (By the Way, the regex demo is highlithing since *start_tag*)

Comment: @VictorBello Yes, it does "highlight" from *start_tag* because the regex consumes all from that tag and end of  previous match till `Foot`. What you need to keep is captured this way. What needs to go is just matched.

Comment: Yes... I used Java Matcher to see the groups, it takes from the last till FOO. The problem is that it might find word with FOO starting, ending or in the middle of the word. Any ideas how could I avoid this?

Comment: @VictorBello Do you mean you need to match whole words that consist of letters/digits/`_`? Use `\\bFOO\\b`